# htaccess redirect stops working after SSL installation

Tags: .htaccess, ssl, redirect

My .htaccess file used to be successful in redirecting traffic from www.mysite.com or mysite.com to www.mysite.co.uk

Then I installed an SSL certificate on www.mysite.co.uk

Subsequently, anyone attempting to reach www.mysite.com or mysite.com received "This site is not secure" or "Warning: Potential Security Risk Ahead" warnings.

My question is whether this can be avoided in the way the redirection is set up in the .htaccess file

The original .htaccess entries that did work were:

```
# 301 Redirect 1
RewriteCond  %{HTTP_HOST}  ^web\.mysite\.com$
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.mysite.co.uk/$1 [R=301,L]   

# 301 Redirect 2
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}  ^www\.mysite\.com$ 
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.mysite.co.uk/$1 [R=301,L]

# 301 Redirect 3
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}  ^mysite\.com$
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.mysite.co.uk/$1 [R=301,L]
```

The equivalent post-SSL .htaccess entries that produce the security warnings are as below. I believe the additional three lines in each entry are not relevant to the problem and have been added automatically for other reasons.

```
# 301 Redirect 1
RewriteCond  %{HTTP_HOST}  ^web\.mysite\.com$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/[0-9]+\..+\.cpaneldcv$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/[A-F0-9]{32}\.txt(?:\ Comodo\ DCV)?$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/\.well-known/pki-validation/[A-F0-9]{32}\.txt(?:\ Comodo\ DCV)?$
RewriteRule (.*) https://www.mysite.co.uk/$1 [R=301,L]

# 301 Redirect 2
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}  ^www\.mysite\.com$ 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/[0-9]+\..+\.cpaneldcv$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/[A-F0-9]{32}\.txt(?:\ Comodo\ DCV)?$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/\.well-known/pki-validation/[A-F0-9]{32}\.txt(?:\ Comodo\ DCV)?$
RewriteRule (.*) https://www.mysite.co.uk/$1 [R=301,L]

# 301 Redirect 3
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}  ^mysite\.com$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/[0-9]+\..+\.cpaneldcv$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/[A-F0-9]{32}\.txt(?:\ Comodo\ DCV)?$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/\.well-known/pki-validation/[A-F0-9]{32}\.txt(?:\ Comodo\ DCV)?$
RewriteRule (.*) https://www.mysite.co.uk/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Any pointers as to how to get mysite.com or www.mysite.com to redirect to https://www.mysite.co.uk without browser security warnings would be very gratefully received.

Comment: The redirections should continue to work as expected _as long as people query using the http protocol_ . Since your ssl certificate most likely does _not_ cover the hostnames `mysite.com`, `web.mysite.com` and `www.mysite.com` there is absolutely nothing you can do when people send requests using the https protocol right away. The reason is obvious.

Comment: The trick part here: most browsers here check if a hostname cn be queried using the better https protocol and will use that without you being able to do anything about that. The only approach that can work is to operate the domains / hostnames on _separate_ systems, so that the DNS resolution points to differnt addresses. That way the autodetection of the first hostnames will only find http to be usable and use that, without such a security warning. But there is no solution based on a single system, sorry.